# Is there a bang version of the 'join' method?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I convert an array to a string in the most efficient manner?

```
 @x = ["foo","bar"]
 @x = @x.join(", ") #=> "foo, bar"
```

Just wondering if there's a slightly better way to do this.

Comment: [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) is the preferred way to do it. It can be done using the [`*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) method in Array, but that's not widely used or known, which can cause a problem if you're working in a team and someone else isn't aware of what it does and "fixes" it thinking it's a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Just wondering if there's a slightly better way to do this.

Would you like this using [***`Array#*`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) ?

```
x = ["foo","bar"]
x *", " # => "foo, bar"
```

Note:- `Array#*` method with an string argument will give you a new string object.

Comment: Since OP was talking about `bang` version, i guess `x *= ", "` would be more suitable

Answer (score 8):

There cannot be a "bang version". It would mean changing the object in-place. But `join` calculates a `String` out of an `Array`. So it cannot be the same object afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

As Arup Rakshit mentioned, the `Array#*` operator is overloaded to call `#join` when provided a string as an argument.  You can take advantage of the syntactic sugar provided with ruby's `*=` operator.  So

```
a = *1..10
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a *= '|'
> "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10"
a
> "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `@x.to_s`? I'm not sure what output you're looking for.

Comment: The output in the question "foo, bar".

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.3 and v2.0, `puts @x.to_s` outputs `["foo", "bar"]`. Ruby 1.8.7 returns `foobar`.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:

```
@x = ["foo","bar"]
@x.join(',').split(', ')
 #=> "foo, bar"
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't this just return the same array and never mutate the `@x`?