# How does the *= operator work?

Tags: ruby

I've searched around a lot but can't find anything on the `*=` operator. How exactly does `*=` work in Ruby?

This answer uses the operator but does not explain how it works:
[Is there a bang version of the 'join' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070923/is-there-a-bang-version-of-the-join-method/19072482#19072482)

Maybe as a bonus some advice on how I would search for something like this in the future. Thanks.

Comment: This is documented as [Abbreviated Assignment](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment).

Comment: Thanks. I had always informally referred to += as the incrementer. Now I know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x *= y` is equivalent to `x = x * y`.

Because your reference to `join`, I presume that you are wondering what is happening with arrays here:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x *= ", "
x
# => "1, 2, 3"
```

When executed with an array as the left operand, `x * y` is [equivalent](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-2A) to `x.join(y)`.

Thus, `x *= ", "` is the same as `x = x.join(", ")`.

As for searching, the key is to understand that every value in Ruby is an instance of a class. To look up methods, look up the class in rubydoc and there you go. To look up an operator, just look up the class of the left operand. There are some exceptional operators (such as `?:` and `&&` that do something weird), but in general the above is solid.

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know arrays treated *= as a join. This is what had been throwing me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, when you write `a *= b`, that is just shorthand for writing `a = a * b`.  So the Ruby interpreter will call the `*` method of the object currently referred to by `a`, and pass `b` to it as an argument.  Then it will take whatever result was returned from that method, and assign it to `a`.

Example:

```
a = 5
a *= 2
# now a is 10
```

The code in the post that you linked to takes advantage of the `Array#*` method, which is documented here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-2A